# How to use jenkins plugin in python script?

Tags: python, jenkins, environment-variables

I've wrote a `script` to create a job in *jenkins*, next in that script I want to get environment variables and set them.

So I want to use `"envInject"` plugin in my script, but I don't know how can I call or bring it to my python `script`?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python env variables can be accessed through os.environ

```
import os
print os.environ['BUILD_NUMBER']
```

see your jenkins_site/jenkins/env-vars.html for more info on build vars available

Comment: what do you mean about "build number" ?

Comment: build_number is environment variable that is available within jenkins node upon build execution and contains build number.

Comment: How can I use "envInject" plugin with it?